# QGIS: Average of digital terrain model for a certain polygon

Tags: qgis, terrain

In one layer I have a lot of different polygons, which represent different areas. In addition I have downloaded a digital terrain model, which shows different slope percentages. All of this works, but I now want to know the average slope percentage for a certain polygon.

Do you know how to do this?

I need it for a university project.

Comment: Have a look at the Zonal Statistics algorithm in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: it worked!! thank you so much for your fast answer!